# Invalid Binary issue while uploading iMessage Sticker App using XCode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, ios10, imessage

I have created a StickerExtensionPack. Apparently, Apple is treating a sticker extension pack as just another app that needs to go in the Sticker Category, fair enough.

However, when I uploaded the binary, I was sent back an email saying that the binary is invalid, because of the following reason:

> Invalid Messages Application Support - The MessagesApplicationSupport
>   folder is missing and you have LSApplicationLaunchProhibited set to
>   true in your Info.plist. Either rebuild your application using the
>   current public (GM) version of Xcode or remove the
>
> LSApplicationLaunchProhibited key from your Info.plist and resubmit
>   your application. Invalid iMessage App - The bundle contains an
>   invalid implementation of iMessage support. Add
>   MessagesApplicationSupport/MessagesApplicationStub next to your
>   Payload directory in your IPA.
>   MessagesApplicationSupport/MessagesApplicationStub must match the
>   binary at TapTeach.app/TapTeach and have no post processing applied to
>   it.

I'm doing a simple sticker pack. I'm on XCode  and can not find LSApplicationLaunchProhibited anywhere in the info.plist within the my files!

Any guidelines on how to resolve this will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: I figured out that turning off Bitcode from "Yes" to "No" helped me avoid this error. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try these steps:

1. **turn off** Bitcode from "Yes" to **"No"**
2. Change the version to `CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION = 1.10.11`.

You don't need to recreate your project, just change the version. I reran the build and it's currently "in review" in iTunes without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

So far, the only way I have been able to work around this issue is to repeatedly delete and recreate the project until iTunes Connect accepts a build. And really, I'm not even sure if the project recreation is actually helping - it could be entirely random - as it still only works about 50% of the time and turning off Bitcode, as mentioned by the OP, did not help.

At least two out of the three sticker packs I am currently working on have had this problem (with Xcode 8.0 and 8.1), so it's befuddling how this cannot be more widespread. I have to assume it's something specific that's causing it, but I am not sure what. So I guess until a proper solution is found: try, try again.